# Is there an equivalent of "&" in R's regular expressions for backreference to entire match?

Tags: r, regex, backreference, capture-group

When I use vim, I often use `&` to backreference the entire match within substitutions. For example, the following replaces all instances of "foo" with "foobar":

```
%s/foo/&bar/g
```

The benefit here is laziness: I don't have to type the parenthesis in the match and I only have to type one character instead of two for the backreference in the substitution. Perhaps more importantly, I don't have figure out my backrefrences while I'm typing my match, reducing cognitive load.

Is there an equivalent to the `&` I'm using in vim within R's regular expressions (maybe using the `perl = T` argument)?

Comment: Beware when you say "in R". There are tons of regex match/replace functions in R: some in `base` package, some in `stringi/stringr`, some elsewhere, etc. The answer depends on the package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In base R `sub`/`gsub` functions**: The answer is *NO*, see [this reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html):

> **There is no replacement text token for the overall match**. Place the entire regex in a capturing group and then use `\1` to insert the whole regex match.

**In `stringr` package:** YES you can use `\0`:

```
> library(stringr)
> str_replace_all("123 456", "\\d+", "START-\\0-END")
[1] "START-123-END START-456-END"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("\\d+", ~paste0("START-", x, "-END"), "123 456")
#[1] "START-123-END START-456-END"
```